# Custom persistent-storage?

Tags: database, storage, local, persistent-storage, persistent-data

I need to make a desktop application that stores data, I want this data to protected, and besides, the user shouldn't have to install any data-servers (i.e. SQL-Server, office etc.).

I thought XML would be the best idea, the question is how can I protect the data whilst enjoying the other cool features of it which is [XML literals and XLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068(VS.80).aspx#vb9overview_topic6)
 (VB.NET is the love of my life).

*UPDATE*:

It's important for me the users shouldn't know I am using an external tool.

Any ideas on this or other approaches would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? It can be bundled with your app as a DLL and a data file - nothing else needed.

EDIT: It's been a while, but I believe that there's also an embedded version of [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html). Never used it though.

Comment: I like the SQLite idea, will check it out; is it compatible with Entity-Framework?
I reupdated my question regarding the XML.

Comment: I don't know if SQLite is compatible with Entity-Framework (I have not used that package/product). There's a .NET plugin that I use for SQLite: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/
Check their site for details.

"users shouldn't know I am using an external tool" - As I said, SQLite will be a DLL and data file bundled with your app. I don't think users would know unless they know what to look for (and where).

Comment: DLL id fair enought, and according to the link you provided, SQLite is compatible with EF as well!

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx), or [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx) if you need a little more oomph.

they're all redistributable - your end-users don't have to install anything.

as for encryption, your app can decrypt database values after retrieving them. or if using an xml file, the file can be loaded into a buffer, decrypted and parsed into an xml doc.

Comment: How big is the distributable binary for SQL Server Compact Edition? I know the Express Edition is not trivial - you would have to build an install script to install and configure it (if the user will not do it).

Comment: CE is under a couple MB's, originally designed for embedded apps like pocketpc. EE can be installed silently w/ msi